# Multiple Apps with the same SHA1

Tags: android, google-api, sha1

I've been having problems with OAuth2 for one of my apps when trying to get credentials for adding an event to Google Calendar. One app it works fine, and in the other (with the exact same code) it doesn't add the event and the error is 'NeedsPermission'.

I noticed that both apps have the same SHA1 (in debug mode). One app (the one that works) is live on the Google Play Store while the other is still being tested. The live app has a different SHA1.

Is it normal for 2 separate apps (in separate projects - not using flavours) should have the same SHA1 and could this be contributing to my problem with the Calendar permissions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell something about SHAs. SHA depends on multiple factors like System, java version,keystore etc if anything from these changes your SHA will change hence you need to allow both SHAs for OAuth but if the SHA is same then their will not be any issue. Two apps can have the same SHA

Comment: OK... thanks for that. Good to know. I'll continue my search for the problem.